# Currency exchange script does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

for some reason i cant get a value of the JSON, can any body help me?

```
function forex() {
    var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
    alert(to);
    var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
    alert(from);
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    alert(amount);
    $.getJSON("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&q=" + amount, function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });

    }
```

Comment: check console for errors and Try `console.log(response)`

Comment: Are you running this script on http://rate-exchange.appspot.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6VKV/)

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you can't access the resource on rate-exchange.appspot.com via ajax because of your Javascript executing on a different domain.

In your case, this particular site supports [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), so you can use jQuery's JSONP implementation to get around the Same Origin Policy. JSONP works by including the target URL as a `<script>` tag and using a callback, which is not bound by Same Origin Policy.

The `$.getJSON()` method will use JSONP if it finds a parameter in the URL such as `callback=?`.

Example:

```
function forex() {
    var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
    var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    $.getJSON("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?&callback=?", { from : from, to : to, q : amount }, function (response) {
        alert(response.v);
    });
}
```

I also changed your manual URL variables to an object which is preferred because jQuery will handle the URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code:

```
$.getJSON("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&q=" + amount, function (response) {
   alert(response);
});
```

use the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&q=" + amount,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(response) {
        alert(response.v);
  }
});
```

Comment: @roee69 may be you need to change the URL.